# Inserted JS elements disappear after ajax reload

Tags: javascript, ajax, facetwp

I am using a WP Plugin FacepWP and want to add reset to the dropdown.
I have used JS to create elements and add the function FWP.reset('country_2').

The problem I have is that when I click reset the page reloads (AJAX I think) and I lose the elements I added by JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function addEle() {
    var newElement = document.createElement("a")
    newElement.className = 'wf-reset'
    newElement.onclick = function() { FWP.reset('country_2')}
    newElement.textContent='Reset'

 var insertReset = document.querySelector('.facetwp-facet-country_2 .fs-dropdown')
   console.log(newElement); 
   console.log(insertReset);
  insertReset.appendChild(newElement)
  };
  window.onload = addEle;
})
```

I hope for my added elements to stay on click.
I believe FacetWP uses AJAX to filter and reset but it resets my added JS elements also.

Added:

> On existing archive (category, tag, shop, ) or search pages, FacetWP
>   will automatically attempt to add a facetwp-template CSS class around
>   the listing. During an ajax refresh, FacetWP will only modify content
>   within that container element. If your pager doesn’t change after a
>   FacetWP refresh, then the CSS class may need to to be manually placed
>   so that it surrounds both the listing and pager.

Sounds like I need to find this class and do something with it to make sure ajax reload keeps the JS I added.

Comment: I am pretty sure that FWP.reset does the page reload, AJAX does not reload your page ;) my be its implementation of reset is window.location.reload() ;)